# R install.packages - 'curl' call had nonzero exit status

Tags: r, curl, install.packages, libressl

At the moment I am getting this error and don't really know how to fix it.
I only get it while working on a `Packrat` R project.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

> curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to cran.rstudio.com:443
> Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
> 'curl' call had nonzero exit status

I recently updated my MacOS version, as well as my R version.

I tried installing libressl/openssl via brew.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found for this problem

1. Install or upgrade libressl, openssl, curl
2. Restart your computer (this is important)

---

On Mac terminal:

```
 brew install libressl
 brew install openssl
 brew install curl
```

Comment: I've had this issue before, this was the fix